# Under what conditions does off-policy SARSA with importance sampling converge?

Tags: convergence, reinforcement-learning, importance-sampling

Under what conditions does off-policy SARSA with importance sampling converge?

I know function approximation can cause problems.
In the tabular case, what is needed to get convergence (to the true Q)?

I am getting exploding Q-values ATM, but I'm not decaying the exploration or learning rate, and I'm using n-step backups.

I'm also curious what the canonical reference for this would be.
Singh et al. (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1007678930559) prove convergence for the 1-step, **on-policy** case.

Comment: Can you share a reference to this off-policy version of SARSA you're curious about?

Comment: Sutton-Barto v2 (2017) draft, section 7.3. (http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/book/bookdraft2016sep.pdf)